# Troubleshooting: Ubuntu 20.04 Server - Ethernet card runs about half expected speed

Tags: networking, 20.04, ethernet, intel

On a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 server, I haven't been able to get this ethernet card to run at more than about half the expected speed on a wired connection.

I get the sense it's not actually running in full duplex since the download speed is consistently close to half that of another computer on a wired connection to the same modem.  But that's a guess.

For instance, my laptop -- also with a 1Gbit card -- routinely shows download speeds in the 800+ Mbps range while this card stays stuck in the low 400s.  The upload speeds are the same on both computers.

After installation, I downloaded and installed the Intel driver directly from
[here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/14611/15817/intel-network-adapter-driver-for-pcie-intel-gigabit-ethernet-network-connections-under-linux.html?).

Advice is certainly appreciated.

```
$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 00
       serial: 68:05:ca:c7:88:22
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=1.8-0 ip=192.168.0.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:17 memory:f7ee0000-f7efffff memory:f7e00000-f7e7ffff ioport:dc00(size=32) memory:f7edc000-f7edffff memory:f7e80000-f7ebffff
```

EDIT:

```
ip addr | grep mtu
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
```

Comment: This is sometimes related to other hardware in the machine. Could you [edit] your post to include the brand/model of your machine as well as the Terminal output of `ip addr | grep mtu`? This may make it easier to identify an avenue for exploration ‍

Comment: Done, @matigo. Thanks.

Comment: Ensure that your link speed is not set to "Auto". I've seen "auto-renegotiation" storms, repeated constantly, eat bandwidth. Pick a number.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions for the number, @waltinator. :)

Comment: Don't forget the computer brand/model bit of the question. I've seen home servers with seriously underpowered processors and IO subsystems that are simply incapable of moving data at the speed of an Ethernet or USB bus ...

Comment: Right, apologies @matigo.  It's an ASUS P7P55D PRO mobo - no brand name, built from parts several years ago. The ethernet card is plugged into a PCIe x1 slot with a transfer rate of 2.5GT/s. After doing some reading, that looks like it's a bottleneck.

Comment: That motherboard is 13 years old, [supporting the first generation Intel Core CPUs and some of the bottom-tier Pentiums](https://www.asus.com/SupportOnly/P7P55D_PRO/HelpDesk_CPU/) from the time. Regardless of what the theoretical limits of the PCIe slot are, if your CPU is not able to keep up with the IO scheduling, you may be bottlenecked 

Comment: The cpu is an i7-860 @2.80 Ghz

Comment: *The cpu is an i7-860 @2.80 Ghz* -> You are bottlenecked.

Comment: Thank, @ChanganAuto.  I came to that conclusion reading more.  The onboard ethernet adapter used to get much higher speeds before it dies - but it had a dedicated chip.